# cannot chain joins using string to left_joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, left-join, ruby-on-rails-5

### Summary:

I have a many to many relationship between attachments and rules, through alerts.
I have a given rule and a given selection of attachments (those with a given bug_id).
I need to go through all the selected attachments an indicate whether there is an alert for the rule or not, with a different CSS background-color.

### Outer Join

I get the correct results with the following query:

```
SELECT attachments.*, alerts.rule_id
FROM attachments
     LEFT OUTER JOIN alerts ON alerts.attachment_id = attachments.id
                               and alerts.rule_id = 9
WHERE attachments.bug_id;
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
bug.attachments
   .left_joins(alerts: {'rules.id' => 9})
   .select('attachments.*, alerts.rule_id')
```

### Database

```
class Alert < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :attachment

class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :alerts

attachments
|  id   | bug_id |
| 14612 | 38871  |
| 14613 | 38871  |
| 14614 | 38871  |

alerts
| attachment_id | rule_id |
|     14612     |    9    |
|     14614     |    8    |
```

### Condition in the From Clause

Without the `alerts.rule_id = 9` condition in the FROM clause, we get the following result:

```
|  id   | rule_id |
| 14612 |    9    |
| 14614 |    8    |
| 14613 |   NULL  |
```

So having a WHERE clause `WHERE alerts.rule_id = 9 or alerts.rule_id is NULL` would lose the result for 14612

So the following won't work:

```
bug.attachments
   .joins(:alerts)
   .select('attachments.*, alerts.rule_id')
   .where( ??? )
```

---

### *Edit*

The above is a simplified and corrected version of my original question.
The original question is below:

alerts belongs to rules and attachments, and attachments belong to bugs.

```
class Alert < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :attachment
  belongs_to :rule

class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bug
  has_many :alerts

class Bug < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attachments
```

For a given rule, I need to show all the attachments for a given bug, and whether there is an alert or not.  I want the following SQL:

```
SELECT attachments.*, alerts.id as alert_id
FROM `attachments`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `alerts` ON `alerts`.`attachment_id` = `attachments`.`id`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `rules` ON `rules`.`id` = `alerts`.`rule_id` AND rules.id = 9
WHERE `attachments`.`bug_id` = 38871
```

I can get this from:

```
bug.attachments
   .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN `alerts` ON `alerts`.`attachment_id` = `attachments`.`id`")
   .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN `rules` ON `rules`.`id` = `alerts`.`rule_id` AND rules.id = 9")
   .select('attachments.*, alerts.id as alert_id')
   .map{|attach| [attach.file_name, attach.alert_id]}
```

What I want to know is how to avoid calling joins with a string SQL fragment.

I'm looking for something like:

```
bug.attachments
   .left_joins(alerts: {rule: {'rules.id' => 9}})
   .select('attachments.*, alerts.id as alert_id')
   .map{|attach| [attach.file_name, attach.alert_id]}
```

Is there anyway to avoid passing an SQL string?

Comment: Notice: the rules.id = 9 needs to be in the join clause, not the where clause, or I will not get the right results.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you will able to get the right results by putting rules.id = 9 in where clause.

```
SELECT attachments.*, alerts.id as alert_id
FROM `attachments`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `alerts` ON `alerts`.`attachment_id` = `attachments`.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `rules` ON `rules`.`id` = `alerts`.`rule_id`
WHERE `attachments`.`bug_id` = 38871 AND (rules.id = 9 OR rules.id IS NULL)
```

Comment: Nope.  I did that in mysql and I get different results.  When it's in the where clause, I only get records where rules.id = 9.  I need it in the from clause so I get the outer join results when rules.id is null.

Comment: That's strange. I was sure it would work. I have to run some checks :D.

Comment: Okay, i know what's the difference now.
Your query results in attachments with all alerts for ALL rules, but only data for those with rule_id = 9 is joined. Still you get other alers which belong to other rules, just without data joined.
My query result is attachments with alerts with ONLY rule_id = 9 or NULL.
Which one do you need?

Comment: I didn't see the or is null.   I'll try it when I get a chance.

Comment: You can do `SELECT attachments.*, alerts.id as alert_id
FROM attachments
  LEFT OUTER JOIN alerts ON alerts.attachment_id = attachments.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN rules ON rules.id = alerts.rule_id AND rules.id = 9
WHERE attachments.bug_id = 38871 AND attachments.id NOT IN (SELECT at.id
FROM attachments at
LEFT OUTER JOIN alerts al ON al.attachment_id = at.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN r ON r.id = al.rule_id
WHERE at.bug_id = 38871 AND (r.id = 9 OR r.id IS NULL))` to see difference between two queries.

Comment: The query to see the difference gave one record.  Using the data I added to the question, `SELECT attachments.id, alerts.rule_id FROM attachments LEFT OUTER JOIN alerts ON alerts.attachment_id = attachments.id LEFT OUTER JOIN rules ON rules.id = alerts.rule_id AND rules.id = 9 WHERE attachments.bug_id = 38871 AND attachments.id NOT IN (SELECT at.id FROM attachments at LEFT OUTER JOIN alerts al ON al.attachment_id = at.id LEFT OUTER JOIN rules r ON r.id = al.rule_id WHERE at.bug_id = 38871 AND (r.id = 9 OR r.id IS NULL));` gives me id: 14614 | rule_id: 8

Comment: The problem with the rule_id condition in the where clause is if there are alerts with a different rule_id.  That is why it has to be in the FROM clause.

Comment: Okay, updated version of your question describes problem better :).
Sadly, I can't be more help. I don't know if this is possible in pure AR.
baby_squeel gem has '.on' clause which could help you get rid of string.